# Unity 2d how to translate on the x axis + rotate without affecting y axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d, translate

I have an object that spawns at the far right of the screen that I would like to travel across the screen to the left. The issue I am having is adding rotation to the object while having it travel left at the same time. What is happening is as the object is rotating its left value is also changing so the object just goes in a circle. What is the best way to keep this object on a straight path while adding rotation?

```
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.Translate(Vector2.left * 5 * Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe add Space.World to the translate

```
transform.Translate(Vector2.left * 5 * Time.deltaTime,Space.World);
```